# How to 'trigger event' an autocomplete list at search box

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try to trigger event after typing text in search Chatbox on Facebook messenger website.

I use this code to interact with search box
document.getelementById('abc').value="David"
then
document.getelementById('abc').dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{bubbles:true}))
but nothing happened

In normally when you typing David on search Chatbox , list of contact person will appear to fit what you type

Please help me to solve this. Thanks alot
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: `document.getelementById()` - is this a typo? Normally it should be `document.getElementById` otherwise it will not work since JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an eventlistner for this.
like

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventlistner('keydown', code_function()
```

This is a real live example for you to understand

```js
document.getElementById("search_users").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  const val = document.getElementById("search_users").value;
  const users = ["Basha", "Adam", "User"];
  const res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].includes(val)) {
      res.push(users[i]);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res.join(", ");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search_users" placeholder="Search...">
<div id="res"></div>
```

I hope this example helps you